# Why does sudo -i command switch to root user?

Tags: linux, terminal, command, line, sudo

I have looked into the manual with `man sudo` and tried the help with `sudo --help`, but it still doesn't explain why `sudo -i` command switches to root user. I have also looked it up on the web.

Comment: From the man page regarding -i: "If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed". That is, it is equivalent to running: `sudo $SHELL`. Which of course starts a new shell as the root user.

Comment: That makes sense now, thanks.